# Pillow - draw a literal tag glyph?

Tags: python, image-processing, unicode, python-imaging-library

The Unifont contains glyphs for Tags, Variation Selectors, and other non-printable characters.

For example at the end of https://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont/unifont-14.0.04/font-builds/unifont_upper-14.0.04.ttf are these tags (as shown in FontForge):

[image: Screenshot showing lots of characters in FontForge.]

Each one has a glyph which *should* be printable:

[image: Outline drawing of a character.]

I want to draw that glyph, using the Unifont, on an image with Pillow.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

text = chr(0x2A6B2) + " " + chr(0x0E0026)

font = ImageFont.truetype("unifont_upper-14.0.04.ttf", size=64)

image1 = Image.new("RGB", (256, 64), "white")
draw1  = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
draw1.text( (0 , 0), text, font=font, fill="black")
image1.save("test aa.png")
```

The first character (a CJK ideograph) draws correctly. But the tag character is invisible.

Is there any way to get Pillow to draw the shape that I can see in FontForge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the short answer is, unfortunately, "no you can't".

Pillow generally uses `libraqm` to lay out text (i.e. do stuff like map the Unicode string to the glyphs in the font, specifically the [raqm_layout](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/fdf4084a7f8ea49bca25158930a8af80cf685b81/src/_imagingft.c#L338) function.

That library in turn has uses a library called `harfbuzz` to do the text shaping.

The tag characters you want, including U+E0026, have the Unicode [default ignorable](http://unicode.org/L2/L2002/02368-default-ignorable.html) property. By default `harfbuzz` doesn't display characters with this property, replacing them with a blank glyph. But it is possible, with the use of flags, to modify this behaviour: specifically, calling [hb_buffer_set_flags](https://docs.rs/harfbuzz-sys/0.1.15/harfbuzz_sys/fn.hb_buffer_set_flags.html) with [HB_BUFFER_FLAG_PRESERVE_DEFAULT_IGNORABLES](https://harfbuzz.github.io/setting-buffer-properties.html) seems like it will achieve what you want, displaying these characters rather than blanking them out.

The trouble is, `libraqm` has no way of setting this flag when it [calls `harfbuzz`](https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm/blob/2ce0061bba867767313b3f6c45438bce56bc72b2/src/raqm.c#L1966) - it does let you set some of the other flags, but not this one :(

To achieve what you want I guess you'd have to use a lower level library - there are apparently Python bindings for both FreeType and `harfbuzz`, though I've not used either so I can't comment on how much pain that might involve.

Answer (score 0):

From [Section 23.9, Tag Characters](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/ch23.pdf#G30110) in *The Unicode Standard,  Chapter 23, Special Areas and Format Characters*:

> ### Tag Characters: U+E0000–U+E007F
>
> This block encodes a set of 95 special-use tag characters to enable
> the spelling out of ASCII-based string tags using characters that can
> be strictly separated from ordinary text content characters in
> Unicode…
>
> ***Display.* Characters in the tag character block have no visible rendering in normal text and the language tags themselves are not
> displayed.**

And from the Unicode Frequently Asked Questions (with my own emphasizing):

[Q: Which characters should be displayed as invisible, if not supported?](https://www.unicode.org/faq/unsup_char.html#3)

> **All default-ignorable characters should be rendered as completely invisible** (and non advancing, i.e. "zero width"), if not explicitly
> supported in rendering.

[Q: Does that mean that a font can never display one of these characters?](https://www.unicode.org/faq/unsup_char.html#7)

> No. Rendering systems may also support special modes such as *“Display
> Hidden”*, which are intended to reveal characters that would not
> otherwise display. Fonts can contain glyphs intended for visible
> display of default ignorable code points that would otherwise be
> rendered invisibly when not supported.

**More resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- [`Default_Ignorable_Code_Point` character property](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Default_Ignorable_Code_Point)
- Section 5.21, Ignoring Characters in Processing in [*Implementation Guidelines*](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/ch05.pdf)
- [Emoji Tag Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-tag-sequence/)